# How to Store a Python bytestring in a Spark Dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm looking at a mystery. I have a bunch of long documents available as Python bytestrings (`b"I'm a byte string"`) in a RDD. Now I convert this RDD to a `DataFrame` to join it to another `DataFrame`. I do that like this:

```
Data_RDD = Paths_RDD.map(open_paths).flatMap(split_files)

Data_schema = StructType([
    StructField("URI", StringType(), True),
    StructField("Content", StringType(), True),
])

Data_DF = sqlContext.createDataFrame(Data_RDD, schema=Data_schema)

print(Data_DF.show(5))

+--------------------+-----------+
|                 URI|    Content|
+--------------------+-----------+
|http://01storytel...|[B@10628e42|
|http://05yxgs.com...|[B@36699775|
|http://1.lhcmaima...|[B@4e569e3b|
|http://100100.ove...|[B@18ae5bab|
|http://1015theriv...|[B@5f044435|
+--------------------+-----------+
only showing top 5 rows
```

these short `"[B@10628e42"` strings seem fairly useless to me and are probably some kind of pointer. The bytestrings are still 'intact' in the RDD because I can still access them. So in the conversion from RDD to `DataFrame` the problem occurs. Now I tried to store the bytestrings in fields with other types, namely `ByteType()` and `BinaryType()`. Both not working because the bytestrings are not accepted with these error messages:

```
TypeError: ByteType can not accept object b'some string' in type <class 'bytes'>
TypeError: BinaryType can not accept object b'some string' in type <class 'bytes'>
```

But it gets even weirder. When I setup a small scale experiment:

```
ByteStrings = [b'one',b'two',b'three']
rdd_ByteStrings = sc.parallelize(ByteStrings)
print(rdd_ByteStrings.take(3))

DF2_schema = StructType([
    StructField("ByteString", StringType(), True),
])
DF_ByteStrings = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd_ByteStrings,schema=DF2_schema)

print(DF_ByteStrings.show())
```

The small bytestrings are not allowed as in a StringType column as well. When I try to run this I get this error message:

```
StructType can not accept object b'one' in type <class 'bytes'>
```

when I try to let spark infer a type it also fails with this message:

```
TypeError: Can not infer schema for type: <class 'bytes'>
```

So any ideas how I could store bytestrings in a `DataFrame` without to `.decode()` them. That is something I only can do after I joined the two `DataFrames` together, because the other one holds the decoding information.

I use Python 3.5 and Spark 2.0.1

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It is not so much a mystery. Step by step:

- Spark uses Pyrolite to convert between Python and Java types.
- Java type for `bytes` is `byte[]` which is equivalent to `Array[Byte]` in Scala.
- You defined column to be of `StringType` therefore `Array[Byte]` will be converted to `String` before storing in a `DataFrame`.
- `Arrays` in Scala are ugly Java artifact and among other problems have no useful `toString` method:

  ```scala
  Array(192, 168, 1, 1).map(_.toByte)
  ```

  ```
  Array[Byte] = Array(-64, -88, 1, 1)
  ```

  ```scala
  Array(192, 168, 1, 1).map(_.toByte).toString
  ```

  ```
  String = [B@6c9fe061
  ```

  This is how you get the content of the column.

There is no type in Spark SQL that maps directly to Python `bytes`. Personally I would join `join` RDDs but if you really want to use `DataFrames` you can use intermediate `BinaryType` representation.

```py
from collections import namedtuple

Record = namedtuple("Record", ["url", "content"])

rdd = sc.parallelize([Record("none://", b"foo"), Record("none://", b"bar")])
df = rdd.map(lambda rec: Record(rec.url, bytearray(rec.content))).toDF()

df.printSchema()
```

```
root
 |-- url: string (nullable = true)
 |-- content: binary (nullable = true)
```

It won't give you that can be used natively (JVM) nor a meaningful string representation:

```
+-------+----------+
|    url|   content|
+-------+----------+
|none://|[66 6F 6F]|
|none://|[62 61 72]|
+-------+----------+
```

but is lossless:

```py
df.rdd.map(lambda row: bytes(row.content)).first()
```

```
b'foo'
```

and can be accessed in Python `udf`:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from pyspark.sql import Column
from typing import Union

def decode(col: Union[str, Column], enc: str="utf-8") -> Column:
    def decode_(bs: Union[bytearray, None]) -> Union[str, None]:
        if bs is not None:
            return bytes(bs).decode(enc)
        except UnicodeDecodeError:
            pass 
    return udf(decode_)(col)

df.withColumn("decoded", decode("content")).show()
```

```
+-------+----------+-------+
|    url|   content|decoded|
+-------+----------+-------+
|none://|[66 6F 6F]|    foo|
|none://|[62 61 72]|    bar|
+-------+----------+-------+
```

Comment: I also had to set PYTHONHASHSEED to make rdd joins possible!

Comment: @user6910411, can u pls reply on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54033132/iterate-spark-dataframe-specific-column?noredirect=1 post

Comment: @user6910411 could you please explain the syntax of decode function so python beginners understand what it is doing.